# Cancelling a planned master thesis

Tags: professionalism, quitting

I was planning to do my master thesis in a big company in my city. The introduction to the topic was quite short, and because it sounded interesting (analysis of support tickets), I agreed to solve this problem.

Now, as I get further into the topic, I realize more and more that it is quite complicated and that I don't really own the necessary skills (like programming or machine learning), because I specialized on other topics in my studies that I cannot use here. I could learn it, sure, but it would take some time and isn't really my field of interest.

The problem is that I already have the contract at home and we planned to start in the beginning of October.
I have another topic in another company offered (DevOps), which I am pretty sure would suit me way more.

How can I politely and professionally say that, after further research on the topic, I think that it is not my strength and I would like to cancel it? 
I don't want to ruin my chances in working there some day.

Comment: Have you signed the contract?

Comment: Not yet, it is still at my place. 
I have an official notice period of 2 weeks after signing.

Comment: But shouldnt I clarify my reasons somehow better? I kind of feel bad because they already put some effort into this now with the contract and now I quit.

Comment: @Ben This is how all interview processes work. The company doesn't get every candidate and the candidate doesn't get every job offer. No one is wasting anyone's time unless you never intended to take the job to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

If you know you are on the wrong track and that's absolutely not what you want to do - the most professional thing is to be absolutely open about this and discuss it with said company. Offer to discuss and try to find a solution that is working for both parties. Maybe you could offer to refer someone for the position in your network...

Do it as soon as possible in order to limit the damages for them. If they are really a good company that you want to work with in the future, they will understand that nobody benefits from an employee that does not really want to be there and they will not stand in you way.

Comment: Plus - OP didn't sign contract yet, so the company shouldn't put too much resources in his work yet.